# echo | awk '{printf "%5s\n", "howardstone"}' What "%5s" specifically does in code?

Tags: awk

```
echo | awk '{printf "%5s\n", "howardstone"}'
```

What does `"%5s"` specifically do in this code?

Comment: What is the intent with the awk print statement ? What have you done to debug it ? Are you expecting us to do your homework ?

Comment: `man awk`, search for `The printf Statement`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo | awk '{printf "%5\n", "howardstone"}'
```

Here , %5 is padding up space before printing the string

similarly you can do padding after the string by doing this

```
echo | awk '{printf "%-5\n", "howardstone"}'
```